# Cron, Ruby and watir-webdriver issue

Tags: ruby, cron, watir-webdriver

i have simple ruby+watir-webdriver example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "rubygems"
require 'watir-webdriver'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
...
# do something
...
browser.close
```

when i run this file manually with:

```
/path/to/my/ruby/example.rb
```

it works fine. When i put this in cronjob, doesnt work...i've changed the cronjob to

```
ruby /path/to/my/ruby/example.rb
```

but was again not working. any ideas how to locate the problem?

@Kevin here the output:

```
/home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:77:in `connect_until_stable': unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:37:in `block in launch'
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/socket_lock.rb:20:in `locked'
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:32:in `launch'
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:19:in `initialize'
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `new'
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:31:in `for'
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.21.2/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:63:in `for'
        from /home/lks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.1/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:35:in `initialize'
```

Comment: Try `cd /your/dir && ruby example.rb` in the cronjob. Also, define "doesn't work".

Comment: it seems, that my example is never executed...browser doesn't starts, the files (i write the results in files) are not modified.

Comment: ruby was installed via rvm...

Comment: I think this is it, env in cron is quite different from your login session. There are solutions, you can google them.

Comment: another ruby example, another machine, same ruby version (installed via rvm) and cronjob works without any problems ;) what cause the problem here? and why only on this machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution - i need to start the browser in headless mode, here my working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'

headless = Headless.new
headless.start
browser = Watir::Browser.start 'http://www.url.com'
...
# do something
...
browser.close
headless.destroy
```

Source: http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is some output to explain what the issue is. Try the following and send us the contents of the cron_out.log file.

```
/path_to_ruby_exec/ruby /path/to/my/ruby/example.rb >/homedir/cron_out.log 2>&1
```

Also, try "/path_to_ruby_exec/ruby" instead of "ruby"

Comment: i have symlink (/usr/bin/ruby) to the ruby exec in my home folder, full path to ruby would not help imho. When i start it  manually (with or without ''ruby'' before the filename), it works always.

Comment: without capturing some output to see why it's failing (as Kevin suggests above) it's going to be hard to troubleshoot this.  Might be permissions of the user that the chron is running under, might be a pathing problem, if it works on one system and not another, that's almost certianly some kind of configuration issue with the system/user etc..

Comment: Can you try this ? echo your existing PATH variable and any other variables that could be related to ruby. Put these into a shell script, make the script executable and invoke the shell script from cron.

Comment: Also, since you are invoking a browser, does it need to be in "headless" mode ?

Comment: i found source with usefull information: http://watirmelon.com/2010/12/14/watir-webdriver-a-detailed-introduction/, i think, i need this in "Hello Watir-WebDriver in Headless (HTML Unit)"...